# dead letters on message from parent actor to child actor, when parent is stopped after sending message

Tags: akka, actor

Consider below code example (Version 1). Here parent actor (ActorA) sends message to child actor (ActorB) and then stops self. Due to self stopping of parent actor, on high load, child actor dies even before picking message from mail box and hence message becomes 'dead letter' (see Sample Output 1 below).

For some reason, I can't modify application design to remove self stopping of parent actor.

Version 1

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Stop
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object AkkaTest extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("AkkaTest")

  for (i <- 1 to 5) {
    system.actorOf(Props[ActorA]) ! i  
  }

}

class ActorA extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int => { 
      context.actorOf(Props[ActorB]) ! i
      context.stop(self)
    }
  }

  override def postStop = println("ActorA - stopped")

}

class ActorB extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int => {
      println("ActorB - processing msg - " + i)
    }
  }

  override def postStop = println("ActorB - stopped")

}
```

Sample Output 1

```
ActorB - processing msg - 2
ActorB - processing msg - 1
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - processing msg - 3
ActorB - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
[INFO] [09/09/2014 08:26:56.101] [AkkaTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://AkkaTest/user/$e/$a] Message [java.lang.Integer] from Actor[akka://AkkaTest/user/$e#-289783076] to Actor[akka://AkkaTest/user/$e/$a#-86921027] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [09/09/2014 08:26:56.101] [AkkaTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://AkkaTest/user/$d/$a] Message [java.lang.Integer] from Actor[akka://AkkaTest/user/$d#-1255514179] to Actor[akka://AkkaTest/user/$d/$a#402128903] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
```

Now consider below code modifications (Version 2). By introducing message acknowledgement from child actor to parent actor and then self stopping of parent actor upon receipt of this acknowledgement, gets rid of dead letters (see Sample Output 2).

Version 2

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Stop
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object AkkaTest extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("AkkaTest")

  for (i <- 1 to 5) {
    system.actorOf(Props[ActorA]) ! i  
  }

}

class ActorA extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int => context.actorOf(Props[ActorB]) ! i
    case m: MsgAck => context.stop(self) 
  }

  override def postStop = println("ActorA - stopped")

}

class ActorB extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case i: Int => {
      sender ! MsgAck()
      println("ActorB - processing msg - " + i)
    }
  }

  override def postStop = println("ActorB - stopped")

}

case class MsgAck()
```

Sample Output 2

```
ActorB - processing msg - 4
ActorB - processing msg - 2
ActorB - processing msg - 5
ActorB - processing msg - 3
ActorB - processing msg - 1
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorB - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
ActorA - stopped
```

Now my question is, is there any other way to achieve the same? I mean getting rid of dead letters.

Answer (score 1):

When a parent is stopped, all its children will be stopped. That is causing the dead letters. The only way to make sure there are no dead letters is to ensure the parent is alive till the child receives the message. I cannot think of any way other than `ack` messages.

Comment: As I said, due to some limitation, I can't modify application design to remove self stopping of parent actor. Anyways, thanks for your answer.